# Web job in AWS like in azure

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

I have created a console application and now I want deploy/run it on AWS. So, I want to configure it like, every x time the job will start run and will start console application.

I have tried AWS lambda but there I didn't find way to run the application like web job.

So is there anyway to run the application as web job using AWS. Can anyone give more insights on AWS lambda ?

Comment: Why -1 given to the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure a CloudWatch Event to trigger your Lambda function every X amount of time, where X can be a [*cron expression* or a *rate*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html).

You can take a look in [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html) tutorial in order to hook a CloudWatch event in your Lambda function.

Comment: Yes I have alreayd done exactly this way.. My only point is how can I upload my code OR exe which is going to run ?

Comment: What language is it written in? your code needs to follow some standards. Once these are in place, you can then deploy the .zip file or point it to a .zip stored in S3. As you move forward and this process gets repetitive, then you may want to take a look into the Serverless Framework or AWS SAM.

Comment: Since you've mentioned azure, here's an example in C# of how your function should look like: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/dotnet-programming-model-handler-types.html

Comment: I have written the code in c# by creating the console application. Where is the option to upload zip file ?

Comment: If by "console application" you mean AWS's Lambda Console, it means your code is already in place. You said you have configured CloudWatch to invoke your Lambda function. I don't really get your question.

Comment: Yeah I configured the CloudWatch in my Lambda function.. But thats a test code only. I have written console application in c# and now i want to run it through Lambda function after regular intervals.

Comment: Grab the code you have created and put it inside the handler of your Lambda. If there are no dependencies it should just work. If there are dependencies, pack them with your application, respecting a 250MB limit.